# Angular - Table with dynamic rows without ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an app I am working to re-create in angular. One section is a list of items that currently has 140 different items. Each item has a table with 1-4 rows, and differing numbers of columns (usually 6-20).

The way the information works, we really need to show all the items to start. However, the processing time to render the tables using ng-repeat, as well as the massively exponential number of scopes is prohibitive, especially since some users will have older computers (although likely running FF or Chrome, so I'm not worried about IE issues).

I have all the data locally in a json array, and I can format it as needed. Of course, there is filtering, so things will be shown/hidden all over. But the data in the tables is one time bound, and doesn't change.

I'd really prefer to make this something that is in a template. I could either loop it in a javascript array, or create the table data myself that way. However, in angular, templates are not allowed to have logic, so I can't do that.

I'd prefer to do everything rendering client side for speed, so I'd prefer not to have to call up the server to render it.

I could also pre-render it in the json, and use sanitize I believe, but that seems back door and against the separation of interests which is core to angular.

What would be the best practices in this case? I think I've tried about everything, and nothing within angular seems perfomant enough for this case. I'd prefer not to have to use paging, since the users would want to scroll multiple filtered long lists. Any suggestions?

Edit: Now with some sample code:

```
    <table id="{{::item.name}}}" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive text-center" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="header in ::item.tableHeader">{{::header}}</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="diff in ::item.tableInfo track by $index">
                <td ng-repeat="cell in ::diff track by $index">{{::cell}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I used arrays because the order matters, and objects don't always follow the order. Again, with over 140 items, 1-4 rows with 10-20 columns, the scopes become quite costly.

Comment: Did you already try with bind once? I've read about people with similar problem and they used ngReact for that specific use case. Unfortunately, until 2.0, angular performance are not really good, but bind once should help a lot.

Comment: Yup, I did bind once. But the initial load in was insanely slow (5-7 seconds on the older computer I tested on). If I have to go that route, I can, but I know that it will seem like a huge slowdown.

Comment: The only alternative for me it's probably rendering the text server side and use ng-bind-once (so while it's loading from angular, it should still display the text from the server)

Comment: Tables are, by nature, relatively slow. Have you tried using DIVs to lay everything out like a table? We have a page with close to a thousand rows on it and it works fine with no issues.

Comment: @scott That still results in needing SOME way of looping over the elements with a script without creating tons of nested scopes. div or table, it's still needing ng-repeat. Since there is no way that I've seen to embed a script into a view, I have to use ng-repeat.

Comment: Solution is to just make my own directive, using the link function to compile it. Although that has it's own issues now..